# Is the integral functional $I(x) = \int_{0}^{T} \Lambda (t , x(t), \dot{x} (t)) \; dt $ lipschitz around $x_0$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control

Let the function $\Lambda : [0,T] \times \mathbb{R^n} \times \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb R$ be continuously differentiable. Assume the integral functional $I(x) = \int_{0}^{T} \Lambda (t , x(t), \dot{x} (t)) \; dt $ is finite value for all $x \in AC[0,T]$ around $x_0$.

My question:  Is the integral functional $I(x) = \int_{0}^{T} \Lambda (t , x(t), \dot{x} (t)) \; dt $ lipschitz around $x_0$ ? If no under what possible conditions on $\Lambda$ the answer is yes?

P.S:  $AC[0, T]$ stands for the space of all absolutely continuous function $x: [0,T] \to \mathbb R^n$ equipped with $W^{1,1}$ norm which is $$   \| x \| := \int_{0}^{T} \|x(t)\| \; dt + \int_{0}^{T} \|x'  (t)\| \; dt$$